# Django : How can I put the initial data into database by editting migrations file?

Tags: python, django, migrate

I added 'models' and created a file using 'makemigrations'.
I want to have the initial data in the database at the same time as 'migrate'.
However, no matter how much I edit the 'migrations' file, there is an error that says no because there is no 'table' in the database before 'migrate'.
Help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

This is also the nice blog where you can create data migration similar to how you create database migration.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/09/26/how-to-create-django-data-migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Django data migrations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

In the operations, run your actual table creation before running data initialization. Please give code example if you run into problems.